# How can I auto-make (schedule) task in spring mvc maven?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I´m working in a webapp Spring MVC with Maven. I need to make a task in an exactly hour of the day. Help me please!! Some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Stack Overflow! The answer your looking for is called the Quartz library. It works with Spring to execute "Jobs" based on a trigger, such as a cron expression, to define when the job will start.

These will probably get you started:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule

Answer (score 0):

If you run this task by command `java -jar` in linux environment, you can use `crontab` instead.

But if you want to handle this task internal java process, a library named `Cron4j` is a simple, easy-to-use answer; but `Quartz` is a better,newer and more powerful library.